# Scala combinator parsers - distinguish between number strings and variable strings

Tags: scala, parsing, combinators

I'm doing Cay Horstmann's combinator parser exercises, I wonder about the best way to distinguish between strings that represent numbers and strings that represent variables in a match statement:

```
def factor: Parser[ExprTree] = (wholeNumber | "(" ~ expr ~ ")" | ident) ^^ {
    case a: wholeNumber  => Number(a.toInt)
    case a: String => Variable(a)
}
```

The second line there, "case a: wholeNumber" is not legal. I thought about a regexp, but haven't found a way to get it to work with "case".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would split it up a bit and push the case analysis into the `|`.  This is one of the advantages of combinators and really LL(*) parsing in general:

```
def factor: Parser[ExprTree] = ( wholeNumber ^^ { Number(_.toInt) }
                               | "(" ~> expr <~ ")" 
                               | ident ^^ { Variable(_) } )
```

I apologize if you're not familiar with the underscore syntax.  Basically it just means "substitute the *n*th parameter to the enclosing function value".  Thus `{ Variable(_) }` is equivalent to `{ x => Variable(x) }`.

Another bit of syntax magic here is the `~>` and `<~` operators in place of `~`.  These operators mean that the parsing of that term should include the *syntax* of both the parens, but the result should be solely determined by the result of `expr`.  Thus, the `"(" ~> expr <~ ")"` matches exactly the same thing as `"(" ~ expr ~ ")"`, but it doesn't require the extra case analysis to retrieve the inner result value from `expr`.

Comment: Excellent! Had to change {Number(_.toInt)} to {x:String => Number(x)} since I got "error: missing parameter type for expanded function", then it worked like a charm. 
Still curious if there is a case class way of solving it though.

Comment: Well, actually case just defines a partial function.  It lets you do pattern matching on the input, which is really why it's useful.  I could just as easily have written my answer using partial functions (case) instead, it just wasn't necessary.  :-)  (it would have been except for ~> and <~)

Comment: If you mean matching on the whole term though, then I think the answer is "no, there is no way to do it".  Unless the `wholeNumber` method returns a Parser with a different component type than String, there's really no way to differentiate it from `ident` or even "(" ~> expr <~ ")".

Comment: Just realized that I wasn't particularly clear...  Partial functions (defined using case) are precisely the same as plain-old functions, they just allow pattern matching on the input.  Thus:  { x => x.toInt } is the same as { case x => x.toInt }.

Comment: I have solved the original problem thanks to Daniel, but I was still curious about using pattern matching with Regexps, and from reading the book and googling it seems there is no way to do that.