# Finding info on scala operators

Tags: scala, operators

Im reading http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2008/04/external-dsls-made-easy-with-scala.html and I am trying to find info on the "<~" operator, for example:

```
def trans = "(" ~> repsep(trans_spec, ",") <~ ")"
```

I have some reasonable guess that has something to do with the product("~") operator along with lists?

1. What does it do?
2. In the future, how do I lookup operators like that? It is no good to google "<~" for example.

EDIT:

Found the "<~" info in [Scala combinator parsers - distinguish between number strings and variable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256694/scala-combinator-parsers-distinguish-between-number-strings-and-variable-string)

Question 2 remains

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Question 2, unfortunately that is one disadvantage of Scala's allowance of non-alphabetic characters, they're not easily found in search engines. Your best bet is simply to check the Scaladocs of whatever code is in scope.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Question 2, there is an upcoming (time-frame unkonwn to me) addition to the ScalaDoc processor that will produce a cross-reference index that allows you to look up method and field names and see which classes declare or define them.

You can get a preview of this (not integrated with the ScalaDocs, but useful nonetheless) here: [ScalaDoc Name Index](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-6wCO3e3ignMmMxYjkzNTMtNTNjMy00NzY1LWI1YTItMzEwMTQ2ZWI5NDY0&hl=en)